# Encoding problem using facebook.net sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the facebook.net sdk to send articles to a facebook fanpage. 
That works fine except for some swedish encoding problems.
The article heading in facebook looks like this: "H\u00e5ret avsl\u00f6jar om du stressar"
but should look like: "Håret avslöjar om du stressar".

What should I do to fix this?

The code:

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(post.Settings);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.name = post.Name;
parameters.message = post.Mesesage;

dynamic result = app.Api(string.Format("/{0}/feed", post.PageID), parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an encoding issue in the traditional sense (i.e., bytes-to-characters), but rather a JSON parsing one.

The [JSON standard](http://json.org) forgoes traditional encoding conventions, and instead converts non-ASCII characters in to Unicode escape sequences that look like `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is the four hex digits that represent the character's Unicode code point.

All JSON parsers should handle the transformation of these escape sequences into properly encoded characters for you.

In short - almost all the data you get from the Graph API is going to be JSON, so parse accordingly.

Comment: So what you are saying is that Facebook has a bug because they parse the text wrong?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all.  I'm saying your FacebookApp class isn't decoding the JSON for you - so that's a step you'll have to take on your own.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then it has to be a bug in Facebook.net sdk then!? I'm just sending in a plain utf-8 string into the sdk so I can't see how I can do anything else with it.

Comment: I guess so - I've only used the PHP SDK so I can't really say.

Comment: Ok, thanks Peter for your answers. :) I will contact the developers of the facebook.net and check with them.